# Android emulator: How to access a sub-domain, on my PC localhost?

Tags: android, localhost, subdomain, host

I'm building some app using NativeScript and a PHP(run by XAMPP) backend.

I'm Trying to gain access from my Android emulator, to a sub-domain on my local machine. Using 10.0.2.2 works for the root domain:

```
 <Image
    src="http://10.0.2.2/1.jpg"
    aspectFit: BaseStretch
 />
```

This works fine. But, if i try something like this:

```
 <Image
    src="http://playground.10.0.2.2/1.jpg"
    aspectFit: BaseStretch
/>
```

It doesn't work, and i get this error:

> Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to
>   resolve host "playground.10.0.2.2": No address associated with
>   hostname

How can i access a sub-domain?

Comment: What happens if you put a redirect script to playground in http://10.0.2.2 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to be honest...I'm just using the vhosts file of XAMPP to create a virtual host(and also i modify the hosts file in windows).

Comment: @i.brod - Did you ever figure out a solution? I am on day two of pulling my hair out trying to get this to work on a site that requires the subdomains (hundreds of possibilities) in order to determine which content to serve.

Comment: It was so long ago that i just don't remember...